# Change number of ticks in Date column

Tags: python, matplotlib

What can I add to this code to change the number of ticks on the x-axis which represents Date to let it appear?

I just want few ticks

```
plt.figure(figsize= (10,5))

plt.plot(AAPL['Date'], AAPL['Adj Close'], label = 'Apple')

plt.plot(AMZN['Date'], AMZN['Adj Close'], label = 'Amazon')

plt.plot(GOOG['Date'], GOOG['Adj Close'], label = 'Google')

plt.plot(MSFT['Date'], MSFT['Adj Close'], label = 'Microsoft')


plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to be sure your time column type is `datetime`, not `str`. In this case, you should convert it to `datetime` through [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).
Then you can set the number of tick along time axis with [`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_major_locator.html). See [`matplotlib.mdates`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers) for more informations.
You can check [this answer](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
start, end = plt.get_xlim()
plt.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, stepsize))
```

edit: oops. looks like you might need to call get_xlim() on the axes.

```
axes = plt.gca() #gca = get current axes
start, end = axes.get_xlim()
```